# How to plot mean as a barplot using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

If I have a table like this, how do I make a barplot using ggplot with the mean as the height of the bars and error bars as the standard error in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do this most easily in ggplot. It requires transposing your data frame, changing the row names to an actual column, and using `geom_col` with `geom_errorbar`

```r
library(tidyverse)

t(df) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'Condition') %>%
  ggplot(aes(Condition, Mean)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Condition)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - `Standard Error`, 
                    ymax = Mean + `Standard Error`), width = 0.15) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('deepskyblue4', 'orange')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Note though that "dynamite" plots like this are thought be many to be a poor way to present your data. See for example [this poster](https://biostat.app.vumc.org/wiki/pub/Main/TatsukiRcode/Poster3.pdf)

---

**Data taken from picture in question and made reproducible**

```r
df <- structure(list(Sunny = c(3, 0.9128709), Shady = c(4.5, 1.190238
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Mean", "Standard Error"))
```